# CSS Hover not working in IE i tags wrapped in a tags

Tags: css, internet-explorer, hover

I have these links with  classes inside like so

```
<a href="#"><i class="icon-instagram"></i></a>
```

Now I've styled them as such

```
.top-social-icons a i.icon-instagram{
    background:#DB97BE;
    padding:7px;
    transition-duration:800ms;
    transition-property: width, background;transition-timing-function:ease;
}

.top-social-icons a i.icon-instagram:hover{
    background:transparent;
    transition-duration:800ms;
    transition-property: width, background;
    transition-timing-function:ease;
}
```

literally works in every browser except IE I've been racking my brain over this. Sorry if I Posted to sloppy this only my second time ever posting here. I'm assuming it has something to do with the i tags wrapped in the a tags?

[link to site](http://www.fatacceptance.org)

Comment: remember to surround css and html examples in a code block

Comment: thanks i was trying to figure out how to do it

Comment: put link to site in original post if it helps

Comment: can you provide us a link or jsfiddle? It'll make us easier in helping you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aYXE7/3/ is this your expected?? it works fine in IE11 what is your problem?? the background-color disappears on hover

Comment: yes It works in IE 10 aswell. No idea why it's not working in my site. Gonna have to keep messing around i guess

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a `<!doctype html>` decleration at the top of your html page? from [w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp) ie requires it when using the `:hover` psedoclass on elements other than `a`s (you're using it on `i` tags)

> Note: In IE there must be declared a  `<!DOCTYPE>` for the :hover
>   selector to work on other elements than the `<a>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Please try remove transition- property. You should declare them one times

```
.top-social-icons a i.icon-instagram:hover{
    background:transparent;
    /*transition-duration:800ms;
    transition-property: width, background;
    transition-timing-function:ease;*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Eru said, for non-anchor tags also add a doctype, but in this revised CSS it is not necessary:

```
<!doctype html>
```

For modern cross-browser transition (may only work in IE10+ with transitions) support:

```
.top-social-icons a { -webkit-transition: 0.8s ease background, 0.8s ease width;
-moz-transition: 0.8s ease background, 0.8s ease width;
-ms-transition: 0.8s ease background, 0.8s ease width;
-o-transition: 0.8s ease background, 0.8s ease width;
transition: 0.8s ease background, 0.8s ease width; }
.top-social-icons a i.icon-youtube{background:#CB2027;padding:7px}
.top-social-icons a:hover i.icon-youtube{background:none}
.top-social-icons a i.icon-twitter{background:#359BED;padding:7px}
.top-social-icons a:hover i.icon-twitter{background:none}
.top-social-icons a i.icon-facebook{background:#3C5B9B;padding:7px}
.top-social-icons a:hover i.icon-facebook{background:none}
.top-social-icons a i.icon-instagram{background:#DB97BE;padding:7px}
.top-social-icons a:hover i.icon-instagram{background:transparent}
```

Comment: I just want the background to disappear on hover

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
 <div class="top-social-icons">
    <a href="#"><i class="icon-instagram">Insta</i></a>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.top-social-icons a i.icon-instagram{
    background:#DB97BE;
    padding:7px;
    transition-duration:800ms;
    transition-property: width, background;transition-timing-function:ease;
}

.top-social-icons a i.icon-instagram:hover{
    background:transparent;
    transition-duration:800ms;
    transition-property: width, background;
    transition-timing-function:ease;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aYXE7/3/)

[Compatibility browser support for transition effects](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions)